# Are there any records of Woody Guthrie's FBI verses to "Acres of Clams"?

Tags: folk

In Pete Seeger's [Introduction to Acres of Clams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3qfXMP5AbM&index=16&list=PL6JIqyorAI4du6K2ozOHU6mOt3zC7JeOj), he states that he and Woody Guthrie once improvised verses to it, including the verse:

> They asked, "would I fight for my country?"
>   I answered the FBI yea.
>   I will point a gun for my country,
>   But I won't guarantee you which way.

Are there any records of the other verses composed at this time?